# How to use Font-Face to describe the new font in JS or React to provide inline property?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Actually, I am working with the react project where there is a drop-down available for the fonts to be selected and applied to a div to show the example to other users. So please help me out to add dynamic font-inline to the div tag. Or if any better solution please brief a little about that.

Answer (score 2):

From what I could see, I could not guess what you're trying to accomplish, but still I'll try my best:
You have a React app, that has a drop-down of different fonts, and by selecting a font, your user will see a live example of the font in a `div`. Since you're using React, you can use the `useState()` hook to create a state that depends on the value of a radio button corresponding to the font in the UI. Create a component called "FontPreview.js" and add the following:

```
//FontPreview.js
import {useState} from 'react';

export default function FontPreview(){
  const fonts = [ "Poppins", "Open Sans" ] // Add all fonts required.
  const [chosenFont, setChosenFont] = useState("");
  const handleFontChange = ev => setChosenFont(ev.target.value);
  return (
    <div class="font-dropdown">
      {this.fonts.forEach(font => ({font} <input type="radio" value={font} onChange={this.handleFontChange})}
    </div>
    <div class="font-preview" style={{fontFamily: [this.chosenFont, "sans-serif"]}}>
      Here is an example text with the correct font.
    </div>
  )
}
```

In your entry file(usually the App component), import it and render it. Then, in the global stylesheet(usually App.css already imported into the App component, import if not), add the required fonts by using the `@font-face` at rule:

```
/* App.css */
@font-face {
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  src: url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,600;0,700;0,800;1,300;1,400;1,600;1,700;1,800&display=swap');
}
@font-face {
  font-family: "Poppins";
  src: url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a special function in JS for adding CSS rules called `insertRule()`.
Create an empty `<style></style>` in your `<head>` so that it can be referenced using `window.document.styleSheets[0]` , then add this code:

```
var sheet = window.document.styleSheets[0];
sheet.insertRule("@font-face {font-family: 'Lobster';font-style: normal;font-weight: normal;src:url('../../fonts/new_fonts/LOBSTER/Lobster-regular.ttf');}", sheet.cssRules.length);
```

Once the font-face is added globally, then you can update the `<div>` font style using the created font-face